# How to fix ES Lint auto fix warnings?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am getting warnings on all of my local imports on build - I am unclear on what the issue is or how to run auto fix as suggested

[image]

This is what my .eslintrc.json file looks like

```
{
  "extends": "next",
  "plugins": ["simple-import-sort"],
  "rules": {
    "simple-import-sort/imports": "warn",
    "simple-import-sort/exports": "warn",
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "error"
  }
}
```

Comment: `eslint --fix`?

Comment: Did you think to [read the documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/command-line-interface#fix-problems)?

Comment: This just returns the same warnings

Answer (score -1):

add this in your eslint file **.eslintrc**

```
{
  "rules": {
    "sort-imports": ["error", {
      "ignoreDeclarationSort": true
    }]
  }
}
```